# Proof that "if m <= n then max(m, n) = n" in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

Yesterday I asked a question here about a proof in Coq and the answer helped me a lot, I was able to solve many exercises alone and discover new features. Today I have another exercise, which states that `For all m, n, if m <= n then max(m,n) = n`. I tried to do induction after m, but I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Fixpoint max (m n : Nat) : Nat :=
  match m with
  | O => n
  | S m' => match n with
            | O => m
            | S n' => S (max m' n')
            end
  end.

Fixpoint le_Nat (m n : Nat) : bool :=
  match m with 
  | O => true
  | S m' => match n with 
            | O => false
            | S n' => (le_Nat m' n')
            end
  end.
```

Lemma:

```
Lemma le_max_true :
  forall m n,
    le_Nat m n = true ->
    max m n = n.
Proof.
    ...
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the 4th sub-goal.

```
1 goal (ID 39)
  
  m : nat
  IHm : forall n : nat, le_nat m n = true -> max m n = n
  n : nat
  ============================
  le_nat m n = true -> S (max m n) = S n
```

`rewrite IHm` is able to replace `(max m N)` with `N`(for any `N`), under the condition `le_nat m N = true`.

By an `intro H`, you push an hypothesis of type `le_nat m n = true` into the context. Then your `rewrite IHm` generates two (trivial) sub-goals.

In short, in order to solve the 4th sub-goal, you may start with `intro H; rewrite IHm`.

If you forget the `intro H`, you get an unsolvable goal:

```
  m : Nat
  IHm : forall n : Nat, le_Nat m n = true -> max m n = n
  n : Nat
  ============================
  le_Nat m n = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do induction on both `m` and `n` (`m` and then `n`). After that, the goal is relatively straightforward.

Comment: Update: Actually I tried this approach on another problem and it worked, but on this one I don't know what to do after this step: 
Lemma le_max_true :
  forall m n,
    le_Nat m n = true ->
    max m n = n.
Proof.
    induction m as [|m IHm]; simpl.
    + trivial.
    + induction n as [|n IHn]; simpl.
      - discriminate. 
Can you help?

Comment: It's like yesterday's exercise:  If you do `induction m; destruct n; simpl`, you get 3 trivial subgoals. The 4th subgoal can be solved using basic tactics (including `rewrite`).